# Is it possible to play an MPEG2 movie and play a seperate MP3 file?

Tags: audio, windows-ce, windows-media-player, movie

I am using an ARM based system and Windows CE 6.0. I am the OEM.
 Before I start diving into searches and coding examples, I wanted to know whether it is possible to use Windows Media Player for Windows CE 6.0 to play an MPEG2 file (without a sound stream), and at the same time play another MP3 file.

1. Is it possible?
2. Are there any H/W requirements?

If there is a different option of doing this, I will be happy to learn it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem will be to synchronize the two but if you just want to play both, just start the media player twice. If it doesn't let you create two instances, use [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Comment: VLC is not supported under Windows CE (At least I did not find support in the site you gave). Anyway, suppose I have another player to open separately, do you know if there are hardware limitations on an embedded system (ARM in my case)?

Comment: You will have to try. It's possible that the decoding of the MPEG takes too much power. If that's the case, use VLC or Mencoder to mix the two streams.

Comment: I intentionally want to separate the audio and video streams. The processor has video acceleration so performance should not be a problem. Anyway, I understand that the general answer is "should work" -> so marking as answer and thank you.